# Fix up htmlspecialchars()-encoded data inside JSON payload using Play! and Jackson

Tags: java, json, playframework, jackson

I'm consuming a JSON web API that's converting all &, ", ', < and > characters in the data to &amp;, &quot;, etc. It looks like it's using PHP's htmlspecialchars().

I have some working PHP code that deals with this, like:

```
function unescape_special_chars(&$value, $key) {
    $value = html_entity_decode($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
...

$response = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
// the data has been run through htmlspecialchars(), we must undo this
array_walk_recursive($response, 'unescape_special_chars');
```

This is nice, I don't know or care what the structure of the returned JSON object is, but the above walks it and fixes it all up.

I need to rewrite this code into Java, and I'm using the Play! framework. I'm pretty new to Play, and rusty on Java. Here's what I have so far in a util class inside my Play app:

```
protected Promise<JsonNode> consumeApi() throws Exception {
    Promise<Response> resultsP = WS.url(REST_URL).post("");
    Promise<JsonNode> jsonNodeP = resultsP.map(new Function<Response, JsonNode>() {
        public JsonNode apply(Response response) throws Throwable {
            // Here I need to "array_walk_recursive" in Java/Jackson
            return response.asJson();
        }
    });
    return jsonNodeP;
}
```

**How can I do something similar in Java and/or Jackson?** I have a feeling I should be able to traverse the tree model provided by JsonNode, but I could use some suggestions or pointers in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to "array_walk_recursive" the JsonNode tree and fix it up with a custom user-provided callback, similar to my PHP solution above, with the following:

```
public Promise<JsonNode> consumeApi() throws Exception {
    return WS.url(REST_URL)
            .post("")
            .map(new Function<Response, JsonNode>() {
                public JsonNode apply(Response response) throws Throwable {
                    // BEGIN JACKSON RELEVANT CODE
                    return JsonUtils.walkJsonNode(response.asJson(), new JsonUtils.TextFixer() {
                        public String fix(String string) {
                            return StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(string);
                        }
                    });
                    // END JACKSON RELEVANT CODE
                }
            });
}
```

`StringEscapeUtils` is from `org.apache.commons.lang3`. `JsonUtils` looks like:

```
public class JsonUtils {
    public interface TextFixer {
        public String fix(String string);
    }

    public static JsonNode walkJsonNode(JsonNode node, TextFixer fixer) {
        if (node.isTextual()) {
            String fixedValue = fixer.fix(node.getTextValue());
            return new TextNode(fixedValue);

        } else {
            if (node.isArray()) {
                ArrayNode array = (ArrayNode)node;
                for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
                    JsonNode value = array.get(i);
                    JsonNode fixedValue = walkJsonNode(value, fixer);
                    array.set(i, fixedValue);
                }

            } else if (node.isObject()) {
                ObjectNode object = (ObjectNode)node;
                Iterator<String> ite = object.getFieldNames();
                while (ite.hasNext()) {
                    String fieldName = ite.next();
                    JsonNode value = object.get(fieldName);
                    JsonNode fixedValue = walkJsonNode(value, fixer);
                    object.put(fieldName, fixedValue);
                }
            }

            return node;
        }
    }
}
```

Note this is for Jackson 1.9.10, which is what is currently shipping with the latest Play (2.1); Jackson 2.x has some differences. If anyone has any suggestions for improvements, please leave a comment. Hopefully this wall of code will be of some help to future googlers working with Jackson.